How to publish echo bot to Microsoft Team using Visual Studio Kit SDK tool?
Hi I am new to Microsoft Bot Framework. Currently I wish to make a simple echo bot and side loaded into my Microsoft Team. However when i debugging there is no issues with it, and once i make the zip the package and side loaded it. It seems not working, nothing returned. Can I know is it due to the local env file?
I did try change the env.local with local app id, somehow it is not working. The whole process is just purely done from Visual Code Studio. I haven set up anything in azure yet. Does tis could be the issues?

Yes, you need to register Microsoft Entra App and then create Azure Bot resource; where you specify the messaging endpoint. For testing purposes you can use ngrok or devtunnels.
Your appsettings/envs should have:
{
  "MicrosoftAppType": "SingleTenant | MultiTenant",
  "MicrosoftAppId": "<MicrosoftApp_Id",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "<MicrosoftApp_Password>",
  "MicrosoftAppTenantId": "<Tenant_ID>"
}

